# Cannot make POST request to web form using Golang http.PostForm

Tags: go, post, web-scraping

I have a website(search.brak) to scrape. For this, captcha text is required and I have used a service for that purpose. However while trying to make POST request with `http.PostForm` I am not receiving the result as expected.

Code is as follows:

```
form := url.Values{}
        form.Set("searchForm:ddAnrede_label", "")
        form.Set("searchForm:ddTitel_label", "")
        form.Set("searchForm:txtName", "")
        form.Set("searchForm:txtProfTitle", "")
        form.Set("searchForm:txtSpecialization_label", "")
        form.Set("searchForm:txtOfficeName", "")
        form.Set("searchForm:txtStrasse", "")
        form.Set("searchForm:txtPostal", "")
        form.Set("searchForm:txtOrt", "")           //city
        form.Set("searchForm:ddRAKammer_label", "") //member of bar
        form.Set("searchForm:txtVorname", "john")
        form.Set("searchForm:txtCaptcha", captchaSolution)
```

To make POST request, I am using

```
res,err:=http.PostForm("https://www.bea-brak.de/bravsearch/search.brak", form)
if err!=nil{
   panic(err)
}
dataInBytes, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
pageContent = string(dataInBytes)
_ = ioutil.WriteFile("test.html", dataInBytes, 0777)
```

However, this is returning me the same page(search.brak), not the result page(result.brak).

[[NOTE]] This scraping is for educational purposes only!

Comment: I would expect the captcha to be tied to the current session cookie or similar. You instead assume that the captcha is valid without any such context.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I was thinking the same at first. However, it turns out that the form accepts any captcha image provided by the same captcha URL. I tried with attach session cookie along the request header but no luck.

Comment: @anisbhsl the request by the page is made using javascript, and the result is some xml split into two responses where the second one contains the redirect link which points to `result.brak`. However the redirect is in the xml, so it will not be followed automatically by Go's client nor by the browser. It is the javascript on the page that reads the xml and follows the redirect. Also note that the results are associated with the session id and not through some "restful" interface.

Comment: @anisbhsl  So from what I can tell you'll need the session first, then you can make the post request, if the server is happy they will associate the result with your session and send back the xml which is irrelevant to you, you only need to care about  the status code you get back, which should be `200`... after that you need to make another request, *with the same session*, to the `result.brak` url to get the contents of the result page.

Comment: @anisbhsl just to correct my first comment, when successful you get back *just one* response that contains the xml with the redirect link. What *I* though were two partial responses to a single request were actually two responses to two separate requests. The rest stands.

Comment: @mkopriva I tried with your first comment by sending post request to ```search.brak``` with session attached and make another request to ```result.brak```. But I am getting same old response. Could you please elaborate your new approach ? I am quiet stuck on this thing.

Comment: @anisbhsl the approach is the same. You should first take a look at how the page communicates with the server by opening the network tab in your browser's console and going through the steps, then based on what the page does you should design your solution in Go, effectively emulating the page.

Comment: @anisbhsl one thing you can see from the network tab is that a successful search will return a response body like this `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><partial-response><redirect url="/bravsearch/result.brak"></redirect></partial-response>`. So what you can do is to make the POST request, then inspect the response from that and ensure that its contents are the same as the above xml, and if they are then you can make the GET request to the result page. But if the response body is different from that it probably means that the request wasn't accepted by the server.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you! I will try with response body.

Comment: @anisbhsl also when you're inspecting the network tab take notice of *all* the parameters and headers sent in the request by the page. For example the page is sending a lot more parameters than what you're sending from the Go code, those parameter could be critical for the request to be accepted by the server. Same goes for the headers.